# appconfig file for connectionstring in class Library project?

Tags: connection-string, app-config

I have a class library project that requires a connection string be set:

```
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["appDatabase"].ConnectionString;
```

If this was any other project then I would have just added an app.config to set this, but what is the code library equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class library must be being consumed by some host I.e. console app, web app, function app etc. All of those projects support app settings of some sort.

Without knowing the architecture of your solution it is very difficult to suggest the best route but generally your class library really should accept its inputs via its constructor either passed directly or managed via dependency injection.